# Non-parseable POM, END_TAG seen, spring-security-bom

Tags: java, maven

New to IntelliJ IDE and trying to import eclipse project source files. It iss basic spring boot starter code, but to build. Error below:

```
E:\JAVA_FULLSTACK\l2_source\c2_source\Bookstore>mvn
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-parseable POM 
C:\Users\xxxx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring- 
security-bom\4.1.4.RELEASE\spring-security-bom-4.1.4.RELEASE.pom: processing 
instruction can not have PITarget with reserved xml name (position:
END_TAG seen ...</dependencyManagement>\n</project>\n<?xml ... @120:7)  @ 
C:\Users\xxxx\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring- 
security-bom\4.1.4.RELEASE\spring-security-bom-4.1.4.RELEASE.pom, line 120, 
column 7
@
```

And  is screenshot of pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.bookstore</groupId>
<artifactId>bookstore</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Bookstore</name>
<description>frontend part for our bookstore project</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

My Maven version is :3.5.4, and it is not the default Maven of ItelliJ.

Having skimmed around the StackOverflow and failing to find an existing solution, I really hope for some advice on how to solve it!

Also curious about the function of the `spring-security-bom-4.1.4.RELEASE.pom` file is. Why are there duplicate XML attribute settings in the file?

---

Update:
delete the .m2\repository and use Maven-plugin to re-sync the proj solve the problem. 
8-25-2018

Comment: Don't 1) post code as images or 2) post code as off-site links. Post code as text inside the body of your question.

Comment: At the scone example you see at the bottom starting the xml prefixes which looks like some download issues. You should simply delete `$HOME/.m2/repository` and build again..furthermore turn on checksum policy...

Comment: @chrylis thanks for reminding.

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks a lot, it is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should not be any errors. At first, try to resync you maven dependencies by removing the folder `C:\Users\xxxx\.m2\repository` and then go to your IntelliJ -> open Maven plugin (on the right side) -> and sync the project. Also, I'd recommend you to turn on `Enable Auto-Import` for Maven plugin from your first screenshot and use the default Maven provided by IntelliJ.

Comment: It is the problem! thank you a lot. But for the delete operation, does it mean that some dependencies that has been downloaded are not the right version so I have to re-download by the dependencies listed in the pom.xml file?

Comment: No there seemed to be issues during the download which sometimes happens. That's the reason why I recommended to turn on checksum policy...